# Получить имя пользователя pygame-menu

Tags: python, текст, pygame, pygame-menu

Я делаю меню для игры. В меню есть графа ввода имени. Пользователь может ввести туда свое имя, а мне нужно это имя оттуда забрать для дальнейшей обработки. Как мне вытащить имя из этого поля? Есть код:

```
menu.add.text_input('name:', default='player') # ВОТ ОТСЮДА НЕОБХОДИМО ВЫТАЩИТЬ ИМЯ
menu.add.selector('difficulty', [('easy', "EASY"), ('medium', 'MEDIUM'), ('hard', 'HARD')], onchange=change_difficulty, style='fancy', style_fancy_arrow_margin=(0, 0, 0), style_fancy_bgcolor=(0, 0, 0, 0), style_fancy_bordercolor=(0, 0, 0, 0), style_fancy_arrow_color=(220, 132, 201))
menu.add.button('play', start_the_game, DIFFICULTY)
menu.add.button('quit', pygame_menu.events.EXIT)

while True:

    screen.blit(bg_image, (0, 0))

    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    if menu.is_enabled():
        menu.update(events)
        menu.draw(screen)
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вводим новую переменную `USER_NAME`, которую будем использовать в нашем коде:

```
USER_NAME = menu.add.text_input('name:', default='player')
```

В том месте, где нужна эта переменная, например, нам нужно распечатать это имя:

```
print(USER_NAME.get_value())
```